# Problem with coding a function that returns the maximum integer from even positions of a string

Tags: python

Make a function that receives a string containing only digits and may also be an empty string, which returns an integer value which is the maximum of all the digits that are in the EVEN POSITIONS of the original string.

If the empty string, the function should return -1.

For example:

max_even_pos("123454321") returns 5, because 5 is the maximum of 1,3,5,3,1, which are the digits in the original string in even positions.

---

```
# My code
def max_even_pos(st):
    if not st:
        return -1          ### This line satisfies the empty list condition
    for i in range(len(st)):  ### Problem I have. Trying to find 
                                    ## the max integer from even positions
        num_list = [i]         # assigns elements to the list    
        if i%2 == 0:             # checks if elements are even
            return max(num_list)      # result
```

My only problem is trying to get the code to find the greatest integer in the even position of the original string. I think "num_list = [i]" causes the error, but I am unsure how to change this so it executes properly.

As of right now, it outputs 0 for all cases

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If you're getting an error, please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, as that can help track down the problem. In this case, you should consider looking into list slicing or enumeration, as those could both help simplify the task

Comment: Basically whatever string you put it such as 0,1,2,3,4, the output I get is always 0 or for any other string i will still get 0. But for this case, the output is supposed to be 4

Comment: @daren yeah, because any time you do `for i in range(len(st))`, the first iteration `i` will always be `0`, sand you will always hit the `i%2 == 0` since `0%0 == 0`, and then you return `max(num_list)` which is just `max([i]) == max([0]) == 0`

Answer (score 2):

Your current code ensures that `num_list` has no more than a single element.  When you hit the first even index, `0`, you stop and return that index, without regard to the input value.  You have several errors to correct:

- Put the return *after* the loop.  You have to get through all of the input before you can return the required value.
- Accumulate the values with `append`.  Your current code keeps only the last one.
- Accumulate the input values; `i` is the position, not the value.  I believe that you want `st[i]`

Also look into better ways to iterate through a list.  Look at `for` loops or list slicing with a `step` of 2.  If you are ready for another level of learning, look up **list comprehension**; you can reduce this function to a one-line `return`.

Comment: No I put two if statements which ensures if the list is empty, it will return -1.

Comment: That's not the problem point I meant.  Trace your code with `print` statements.  Your assignment ensures that, once you reach the inner `if`, then `num_list` has a single element, no matter how long the input might be.

Comment: @daren that isn't the problem, the problem is how you are handling the string. Your indentation is off, and you don't build your list of digits correctly, a lot of basics here.

Comment: No the indentations are correct, it just might appear wrong because of when I paste my code here it messes up the indentations. Anyways, why can't I just change the num_list[] to something else? For example, just to test cases, when I put numbers such as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in the [] of num_list, it works but only shows the number 9 as the output

Comment: @daren **you must post the code exactly as you have it**. Indentation is semantically relevant in Python, we cannot just guess, and regardless of what your indentation is, your code would not do what you think it is doing.

Comment: My bad, the indentation is exactly the same as my original code. Regardless if I change the indentation of my original code, it won't even execute. As the indentations are right now, it executes the code but incorrectly

Comment: Yeah it shows 0 as the output for every string containing digits inputted

Comment: @daren no, the code gets executed correctly. Your code simply isn't doing what you think it is doing. You should read this answer, because it is telling you **exactly** what your mistakes are.

Comment: Doing only one suggestion partially will not make your program work.  You need to do them all.  Also, try tracing your code as I suggested.

Comment: Wait check my updated code to understand each line of my code. I am new to python so some lines of code may not make sense

Comment: I'll wait until you assimilate my answer.

Comment: Wait I fixed my code now, but it doesn't all conditions. It satisfies all conditions now except one, but for st = "121212" I get the output 2 but its supposed to be 1.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? your answer is confusing me. I just changed one part of the code and it suddenly works for all conditions except for one

Comment: @juan I'm just very confused on how to translate the question into python and the answer. I'm trying to find an easy way to solve this

Comment: @daren there are many ways of doing this. Likely, you should stick to the sort of answer you are attempting to create, because clearly this is for some exercise and you should probably avoid using more advanced constructs. For example, your entire function could just be: `return -1 if not num_list else max(map(int, num_list[::2]))`

Comment: @juan right now, the only thing I changed was the last line. Changed it to max(st), and it works for every condition except for  st = "121212" I get the output 2 but its supposed to be 1. Why is this? If it works for every other condition, why wasn't able to detect this one?

Comment: Nvm I fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

@Prune is correct. Maybe comparing the lines below to your original will help you for next time....

```
test_string = "123454321"
def max_even_pos(st):
    num_list = []
    if not st:
        return -1
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            num_list.append(st[i])
    return max(num_list)

print(max_even_pos(test_string))
```